# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have trouble accessing the length of an undefined array here is a snippet of my code:

```
const pages = []
for(let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(users.length / itemsPerPage);i++){
   pages.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Undefined variables have no `.length` property. If you were expecting the `.length` to be zero, you have to declare users as an empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think  when you fetch the data, you are overwriting your state to `{isLoaded: true, users: result.users}` and deleting everything else, use the spread operator instead, so the properties you arent updating stay, like `{...this.state, isLoaded: true}`, so that way you keep everything else.